# How can I scale up some of control curves of the Human Meta-rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

I've made a Rigify skeleton. After I generated a rig some of the control curves were created too small and they are hidden in my character's geometry. I tried to fix 'em in the edit mode, but the curves disappear once I activate the edit mode. So how can I scale up the curves? And also I'd like to change some shapes a bit. So can I do it on one side and have the other side fixed automatically?

Comment: Why not enable Properties -> Armature -> Viewport Display -> In front ?

Comment: It sure solves the difficulty of the selection. But it still doesn't make the controllers intuitive, forcing me to search for the tiny little curves inside a very fat character. =D Also not that great visibility within the shading mode. having the well-sized controllers in the right place speeds ups the work.  So I really hope that there might be a solution...

Answer (score 3):

In pose mode, select the control bone you want to alter, go to bone properties, viewport display, and use the scale value.

If more than one bone are selected and you press Alt button when validating, the same scale is applied to all selected bones.

You can also edit the shapes, they are nothing but a simple mesh, note that the edit has to be performed orienting the mesh in object mode aligned with the bone, so that the edits are aligned too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An update to this request since I've started flopping about inside ARP:

Today's current ARP version (3.69.23) features a button directly beneath the "Match To Rig" button in the RIG tab.  This lower button: *Edit Shape*.  Select the control you wish to edit, hit this button and then modify the spline geometry as desired.  The button converts into *Apply Shape* which you should hit once you're done editing.  Pretty straightforward.